# In which comic book did Steppenwolf stab Wonder Woman, and did she die as a result?

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, wonder-woman

What was the comic book in which Steppenwolf stabbed Wonder Woman? I saw a comic panel once where he stabbed her.

And did she really die from the wound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was apparently [Earth-2’s post-Flashpoint Wonder Woman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Diana_of_Amazon_Island_(Earth_2)) (or “Diana of Amazon Island”), and she did indeed die from the wound, in [Earth 2, Vol.1, issue #1 (July 2012)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_2_Vol_1_1).

Here is, I think, the panel you’re referencing — in spoiler tags for anyone who doesn’t particularly fancy seeing a drawing of someone being stabbed:

> [image: Earth-2’s Wonder Woman being stabbed]